# Prevent direct access to webserver files

Tags: webserver, url

How can I prevent direct access to my /css and /scripts folders, and there contents? Also, is there a way I can prevent direct access to index.php? (The right way is to just go to my website, which automatically loads the home page through index.php, or go to the specific page with website.com/thepage, which goes to index.php?page=thepage. None of my links directly go to index.php.)

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "direct access"? And why do you want to prevent that?

Comment: By directly access I mean just entering in the URL and viewing it, when it's only meant to be used e.g. to style the page.

Comment: And for things like php files that send an email from a form, I don't want users directly going to that url, it would cause an error.

Comment: Just _how often_ do you get users entering random URLs in your domain, and complaining when they get errors, or "gibberish" which is actually CSS?

Comment: website.com/send isn't that 'random', but anyway I'm doing it a different way now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a web development guy, but from what I understand the following are true:

- Loading your `index.php` in a browser spits out the page code that the browser receives and renders.  So the browser requests:

  ```
  http://website.com/index.php
  ```
- The page code it gets includes certain CSS and Javascript files from your `css/` and `script/` directories.  So the browser requests:

  ```
  http://website.com/css/mystyle.css
  http://website.com/script/myscript.js
  ```
- In order to include these files, the browser must request those URLs from your webserver, and your webserver must serve them from those URLs.

If so, then **no**, you can't do what you're asking **without changing how your CSS and script files are included.**

You **could change the PHP**, so that it's output doesn't include links to external files, but rather includes the content of those files **as inline sections** of the PHP output.  **Then** you can use the webserver's standard access controls to disallow access to the `css/` and `script/` directories.

Comment: Ok maybe I shouldn't really bother with it it then..

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off directory browsing and then people will not be able to see the contents of folders which do not have a default document defined. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Well thats already impossible since website.com/css won't list the directory, it will try to do index.php?page=css (and then redirect to error page). But website.com/css/style.css will display it in plain text.